# Use isStrongPassword in validation schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, express-validator

I'm trying to define a schema using express-validator in which I set the "isStrongPassword" option. The "usernameSchema" works fine, but the "passwordSchema" doesn't pass my entered passwords through, even if they match the requirements.

Here is my code:

userRouter.js

```js
const { usernameSchema, passwordSchema } = require("../services/validationSchemas");

router.post("/register", checkSchema({ username: usernameSchema, password: passwordSchema }), (req, res) => {
  const result = validationResult(req);
  if (result.isEmpty()) {
    res.json({
      username: req.query.username,
      password: req.query.password
    });
  } else {
    res.send({
      errors: result.array()
    });
  }
});
```

validationSchemas.js

```js
const usernameSchema = {...};

const passwordSchema = {
  errorMessage: "Enter a valid password.",
  trim: true,
  notEmpty: {
    bail: true
  },
  isStrongPassword: {
    minLength: 8,
    minLowercase: 1,
    minUppercase: 1,
    minNumbers: 1
  },
  errorMessage: "Password doesn't match the requirements."
};

module.exports = {
  usernameSchema: usernameSchema,
  passwordSchema: passwordSchema
};
```

Even if I enter a password that matches the requirements, I get the following error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "type": "field",
            "value": "124sdjAfsd",
            "msg": "Password doesn't match the requirements.",
            "path": "password",
            "location": "query"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using schema validation, you need to pass options under the `options` property of the validator. They won't work if you pass them directly to the validator.

```
isStrongPassword: {
  options: {
    minLength: 8,
    minLowercase: 1,
    minUppercase: 1,
    minNumbers: 1
  }
}
```

[Docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/api/check-schema#validator-options)

Answer (score 3):

Did some testing now (version 7.0.1)

Express validator uses the default values unless you override them, you are not passing because you didn't override the minSymbols, so it is requiring 1 special char.

BUT If you use schema, there is a bug, you simply cannot override the default values (8 chars, 1 lower, 1 upper, 1 number and 1 special),

I can pass with this password: `aA1@1245` even with this crazy config:

```
const passwordSchema = {
    trim: true,
    notEmpty: {
        bail: true
    },
    isStrongPassword: {
        minLength: 1000000000,
        minLowercase: 1000000000,
        minUppercase: 1000000000,
        minNumbers: 1000000000,
        minSymbols: 1000000000
    },
    errorMessage: "Gotta be kidding"
};
```

To be able to achieve what you want (override the minSymbol) you have to use chain validation:

```
const passwordConfig = {
    minLength: 8,
    minLowercase: 1,
    minUppercase: 1,
    minNumbers: 1,
    minSymbols: 0 // dont require special chars
}

router.post("/register",
    checkSchema({ username: usernameSchema }), // first middleware - schema validation
    query('password').isStrongPassword(passwordConfig), // second middleware - chain validation
    (req, res) => {
        const result = validationResult(req);
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            res.json({
                username: req.query.username,
                password: req.query.password
            });
        } else {
            res.send({
                errors: result.array()
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll test it once I get home but I'm curious: Is there a way to combine the checkSchema method and chain validation?

Comment: Yes, my answer is already combined, you just pass another middleware, you can pass any  number of middlewares you want, just separate them by commas

Comment: No, I meant if it's possible to combine them for the same element. So a schema validation for "password" and a chain validation for "password". Do you just add another middleware?

Comment: Oh i see, yes, you can add the password schema back in the checkshema (wihout the isStrongPassword of course). Also to add a message in chain validation you can chain .withMessage